# MYSQL Update single records a table with MIN & MAX values from multiple records in 2nd table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 tables houses & availability - I want to find the min and max for the RENT field for each HOUSEID in AVAILABILITY this contains many records per JOUSEID , then UPDATE the HOUSES table fields MIN_RENT and MAX_RENT, the HOUSES table contains only one entry per HOUSE ID

```
HOUSES

houseid min_rent max_rent
    121    40.00    90.00
    122    50.00    80.00
    123    40.00   100.00

AVAILABILITY

house_id date     rent
     121 01/01/12   40
     121 01/02/12   50
     121 01/03/12   60
     121 01/04/12   90
     122 01/01/12   40
     122 01/02/12   50
     122 01/03/12   60
     122 01/04/12   80
     123 01/01/12   40
     123 01/02/12   50
     123 01/03/12   60
     123 01/04/12   90
```

Regards
         Martyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a faster solution

```
UPDATE
     HOUSES H
    ,(
        SELECT
             house_id
            ,MIN( rent ) AS min 
            ,MAX( rent ) AS max
        FROM
            AVAILABILITY
        GROUP BY
            house_id
    ) AS A
SET
     min_rent = A.min
    ,max_rent = A.max
WHERE
    H.house_id = A.house_id
```

Comment: Tried this - fast but did not update the min_rent or max rent in the HOUSES

Comment: it should update. can you check the subquery aliased A, returns the right rows?

Comment: Yep the sub query  -   SELECT
             house_id
            ,MIN( rent ) AS min 
            ,MAX( rent ) AS max
        FROM
            AVAILABILITY
        GROUP BY
            house_id  - returns the correct rows

Comment: does it give any error or notice when you run the update query?

Comment: also, what is you mysql version and what engine are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - missed this one - my bad typeing - got it to work with your code helped me sort it